# Can anyone enter with valid visa about expire

Tags: visas, schengen

I have a schengen visa which will expire in January 16th but I will be in Italy on January 12th can I enter shengan state 10 days from my entry.

Comment: What do you mean by "10 days"?  The 12th to the 16th, counting inclusively as they do, is five days.  You'll have to leave on or before the 16th.

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you are asking. Are you planning to enter on the 12th and stay for 10 days until the 21st or 22nd? If your visa expires on the 16th, you are not allowed to stay beyond that date.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can report for entry into Schengen zone with a visa expiring soon. As long as you plan to leave before or on the expiry date of your Schengen visa and you convince them why not!